# Issues in Cygwin view Plot , cannot load font

Tags: cygwin, xterm

I installed `cygwin` on `Windows`. Using `ASWING` with linked `Arpack` library.
I've got troubles to create the plot!
Anybody there who is into `cygwin`? Any suggestions how to solve that? Please check the picture! 
Let me know if you need some more informations!

[image: Picture shows the errors]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is usually better if you can post the exact error and (maybe) why you think you might be getting that error as text instead of an image. Please read [mcve] to know why.

Comment: xterm's in the picture, but unrelated to the plotting problem.